# Insert String into Blank columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to insert text to any columns that is blank. The file is tab separated and im trying to insert text into any column that is blank. e.g.

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
string1  decs1    1234
         desc1    1255
string3           3443
string4  desc1    1
string5           435
```

I am trying to only insert the text NULL into column1 or 2 that is blank. So it would look like this. (If column 2 is empty then there is a double tab between column 1 and 3)

```
column1  column2  column3
string1  decs1    1234
null     desc1    1255
string3  null     3443
string4  desc1    1
string5  null     435
```

I've tried using `awk` but my test will insert the NULL text into all of column2, but if there is a blank entry there it truncates the 3rd column into column2.

```
awk '{sub("$", "NULL", $2)}; 1' file.txt > file2.txt
```

result is something like this

```
column1  column2 column3
string1  desc1NULL 1234
string2  desc1NULL 1255
string3  3443NULL
string4  descNULL  1
string4  435NULL
```

I am obviously using the incorrect syntax but not sure how to correct it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to do it with `sed`:

```
sed -E -e :1 -e 's/(^|\t)(\t|$)/\1null\2/;t1' yourfile
```

(For portability, use an actual TAB character instead of `\t`, but this would probably not survive browser copy/paste.)

How do you detect an empty field? It's either

- a tab at the beginning of a line (`^\t`) or
- two tabs with nothing in between (`\t\t`) or
- a tab at the end of the line (`\t$`)

In all of these cases `s`ubstitute your pattern between both matches.

In case there are two empty fields after another, we need to loop, so `t1` jumps to the `:1` mark, if something was substituted.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '$1==""{ $1="NUll" }  $2==""{ $2="NUll" }1' infile
```

---

With *`sub("$", "NULL", $2)`*, you are calling the sub() function to replace the End-of-String `$` of column#2 `$2` with "NULL" string. Also you to repalce those columns with "NULL" only if they are empty which with that way with using sub(), you can do something like:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
  $1==""{ sub(/.*/, "NULL", $1) }
  $2==""{ sub(/.*/, "NULL", $2) }
  $3=="" { "......" }
  # etc ...
1' infile
```

Or maybe:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
  { sub(/.*/, ($1==""?"NULL":$1), $1) }
  { sub(/.*/, ($2==""?"NULL":$2), $2) }
  # continue ...
1' infile
```

... but that is just somehow bad compare to the first commnad earlier; Or you might to use below variant in case replacement job is not only limited to two columns but consider it's in *N* columns.

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' -v N=2 '{
  while(colNr++<N){
      $colNr=($colNr==""?"NULL":$colNr)
  }
  colNr=0
}1' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="") $i="null"} 1' file
Column1 Column2 Column3
string1 decs1   1234
null    desc1   1255
string3 null    3443
string4 desc1   1
string5 null    435
```

To use `sub()`s would be:

```
$ awk '{ while(sub(/\t\t/,"\tnull\t")); sub(/^\t/,"null\t"); sub(/\t$/,"\tnull")}1' file
Column1 Column2 Column3
string1 decs1   1234
null    desc1   1255
string3 null    3443
string4 desc1   1
string5 null    435
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

The following two code examples work:  the first example uses Raku's `subst()` substitute command, while the second example uses `split()`/`join()`. Below, the code can be changed to return `Nil` (how Raku internally represents missing values), or `<NA>` or `␀`, as the user sees fit:

```perl
perl6 -e '.put for lines.map: *.subst(:global, / <?after ^ || \t > \t /, "NULL\t").subst(:global, / \t $ /, "\tNULL");'
```

OR

```perl
perl6 -e '.put for lines.map: *.split(/ <?after ^ || \t > \t /).join("NULL\t").split(/ \t $ /).join("\tNULL");'
```

[Note below how each line has two `\t` representing the whitespace between three columns, and how (when a single field is blank), only two strings remain].

Sample Input (whitespace visualized with `raku -ne '.raku.put;'`):

```
"Column1\tColumn2\tColumn3"
"string1\tdecs1\t1234"
"\tdesc1\t1255"
"string3\t\t443"
"string4\tdesc1\t1"
"string5\t\t435"
"string6\t436\t"
```

Sample Output (whitespace visualized with `raku -ne '.raku.put;'`):

```
"Column1\tColumn2\tColumn3"
"string1\tdecs1\t1234"
"NULL\tdesc1\t1255"
"string3\tNULL\t443"
"string4\tdesc1\t1"
"string5\tNULL\t435"
"string6\t436\tNULL"
```

Alternatively, a quick-and-dirty way to get a cognate result is to `split` on tabs, then go through checking each field to see if `.chars` is 0 (i.e. False), or checking for empty-string directly with `when "" {…}`. These solution are fine if you want to concatenate all lines into a single line, however they all are *not-quite-right* for the TSV problem as they leave a trailing `\t` tab at the end of each line. However a second run using `raku -pe 's/ \t $//'` easily fixes it:

```perl
raku -ne 'for .split("\t") { if .chars {"$_\t".print} else {"NULL\t".print}; }; "\n".print;' 

#OR

raku -ne 'for .split("\t") { .chars ?? "$_\t".print !! "NULL\t".print }; "\n".print;'  

#OR

raku -ne 'for .split("\t") {when "" { "NULL\t".print }; default {"$_\t".print};}; "\n".print;'
```

Really, it's no secret that the most robust way to do this is with a CSV parser. Raku's `Text::CSV` module is written by the same developer who wrote Perl5's `Text::CSV` module, and thus should be reliably able to handle empty-fields, embedded-newlines, etc. One caveat is the ability to output user-defined strings for blank values is not yet implemented, however adding the parameter `quote-empty => True` will return `""` where blank fields are found. Below, remove the final output call to `sep => "\t"` to return the default `CSV`:

```bash
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'csv(in => $*IN, sep => "\t") andthen csv(in => $_, out => $*OUT, quote-empty => True, sep => "\t");'  < file.txt
Column1 Column2 Column3
string1 decs1   1234
""  desc1   1255
string3 ""  443
string4 desc1   1
string5 ""  435
string6 436 ""
```

Finally, if you're okay with blank fields being represented by `""` but using an external module is problematic, you might be able to adapt Raku's internal representation for your own use (via a call to `.raku`). Below ranks among the simplest coding solution posted (with the caveats mentioned):

```bash
~$ raku -ne '.split("\t").list.raku.put;'  file.txt
("Column1", "Column2", "Column3")
("string1", "decs1", "1234")
("", "desc1", "1255")
("string3", "", "443")
("string4", "desc1", "1")
("string5", "", "435")
("string6", "436", "")
```

See the U&L URL below for more Raku solutions.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654184/227738
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Using the csvkit tools to create an intermediate JSON document that we modify by replacing all non-existing values with the string `NULL`, and then transforming that modified JSON document back to tab-delimited CSV:

```bash
csvjson -t file |
jq '.[] |= map_values(. // "NULL")' |
in2csv --blanks -f json | csvformat -T
```

Here, we first use `csvjson -t` to parse the tab-delimited input from the file called `file`, outputting JSON.  We then invoke `jq` to modify the generated document, replacing all empty values with the string `NULL`.  The `in2csv` call reads the JSON document and generates CSV, using `--blanks` to avoid replacing the `NULL` strings with empty values. Then, finally, reformatting the CSV data to be tab-delimited using `csvformat -T`.

---

The same thing, but allowing `jq` to work on a stream of individual rows instead of having to read an array of the whole data set.  Then streaming the data in the same manner to `in2csv`.

```bash
csvjson --stream -t file |
jq -c 'map_values(. // "NULL")' |
in2csv -f ndjson --blanks | csvformat -T
```